# Include of non-modular header inside framework module in iOS Flutter Plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to add an Obj-C header file in my `TrsurveysPlugin.h`, however it shows the error -

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'trsurveys.TrsurveysPlugin': '/Users/arnav/Desktop/taprsurveys
```

There is no bridging header file in my Flutter plugin for me to call this anywhere else, here's my podspec,

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'trsurveys'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
  s.dependency 'TapResearch'
  s.static_framework = true
  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice. Only x86_64 simulators are supported.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'x86_64' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

Comment: Hi, you resolve it?